# MS Access hidden column value from combo box to another field

Tags: ms-access

So I have a database where I have a list of defined terms that get added to a record.

I have it set up so a combo box displays the terms and these get added to a field.

What I would like is the definition field for the term to appear in a text box next to the combo box.

So far I can get it to display the term by simply referring to it by having the control source be "=[Term]". But what I want is to refer to a column within the query used to get the terms in the combo box.

How would I do this? Is there a way of getting the value from one of the hidden columns of a combo box to appear in another place? Even as hover text would be good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use:

`=[Term].[Column](n)`

where *n* is the zero-based index of the column to retrieve.